# Create two independent desktops?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop-application, desktop, multiple-monitors

I'm running some kind of POS application which makes exclusive use of the whole desktop to not to let the user access any of the Windows system functions. To do this, I use the WinAPI functions

```
CreateDesktop()
OpenDesktop()
```

to open an own desktop and to start this application there. This works fine for one desktop.

Now there is the possibility to connect a second monitor to this PC. Windows by default extends its desktop over the full area of both monitors. But this is not a solution for my application, here I want to start two GUIs in the same manner as described above but on every monitor exclusively.

But: I do not see any possibility to hand over a monitor identifier to the functions CreateDesktop()/OpenDesktop(). So any idea how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible, as far as I know.  But you could run both GUIs on the two different parts of the same desktop and still keep them isolated from Explorer.  (Well, unless the user knows about control-alt-delete.)

Comment: You don't need a separate desktop just to display a GUI on a specific monitor.  Simply set the GUI's dimensions to be within the bounds of the desired monitor within the overall [virtual screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145136.aspx).  You can query a monitor's bounds using [`GetMonitorInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901.aspx). If you don't want a non-admin user to access the rest of the system, run the OS in kiosk mode, or set up security policies.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: this is not a soluition. The existing application makes use of dialogues - and with the one-desktop-two-windows-solution a user from one GUI would be able to drag such a dialogue (partially) onto the screen of the other monitor

Comment: @Elmi not if the dialog is coded to prevent such a drag. It is very easy to handle messages like [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653.aspx) to prevent unwanted moves/resizes and confine the dialog to the bounds of a specific monitor.